# status bar in iOS8 becomes black on app launch

Tags: ios8

I am working on ios8 application. When I launch the app, the status bar briefly remain black before becoming normal. I have added
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:NO];
in the webViewDidFinishLoad. I have 
UIStatusBarStyle
    UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque 
in my plist file. I want normal status bar on top when the application launches.
This happens only on iOS8.
Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

`UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` has been deprecated since iOS 7, and from the way that the enum’s set up, it looks like it might have a value that UIKit doesn’t know what to do with:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIStatusBarStyle) {
    UIStatusBarStyleDefault                                     = 0, // Dark content, for use on light backgrounds
    UIStatusBarStyleLightContent     NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) = 1, // Light content, for use on dark backgrounds

    UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use UIStatusBarStyleLightContent") = 1,
    UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque      NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use UIStatusBarStyleLightContent") = 2,
};
```

Note that `…Opaque` has a value of 2, which doesn’t correspond to either of the prescribed styles. I’d suggest switching the style value in your Info.plist to UIStatusBarStyleLightContent. `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` is also an odd place to be setting the style—it’d be more appropriate to put that in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` or similar.

Comment: I tried adding your solution. Whenever I launch the application, the status bar remains black for a split second and then becomes normal. Same is the case if I put the application in the background and launch it from there. This happens only on iPhone 6 and 6 plus.Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this on the simulator, by any chance? I’ve hit a bug before where the status bar doesn’t behave correctly in the sim but works fine on a device.

Comment: I have tested both on device as well as simulator and it behaves the same.

Comment: Hm. Sounds like your only option is [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com), then. It’d be helpful to include a sample project that reproduces the issue.